# ESP8266 not sending temperature data to text message

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, esp8266, c

i am trying to use a ESP8266 module to send temperature data using twilio and send it to my phone via text message. However it does not send the sensor data but the text i placed. Is it possible if i can get it to send sensor data instead? If so how can i do this?

```
strcat(data,"From=");
    strcat(data,PHONE_FROM);
    strcat(data,"&");

    strcat(data,"To=");
    strcat(data,PHONE_TO);
    strcat(data,"&");

    strcat(data,"sid=");
    strcat(data,TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID);
    strcat(data,"&");

    strcat(data,"token=");
    strcat(data,TWILIO_TOKEN);
    strcat(data,"&");

    strcat(data,"Body=");
    const char TEXT_MESSAGE_BODY []  = "temperature", temperature;
    strcat(data,TEXT_MESSAGE_BODY);

    wifi.httpPost("iot-https-relay.appspot.com","/twilio/Messages.json",data);
```

temperature should be getting sensor raw data and paste it after the "temperature" but it is not working.

Comment: Do you know that you can get values from the sensor correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do with the line:

```
const char TEXT_MESSAGE_BODY []  = "temperature", temperature;
```

This will not assign the value in temperature to TEXT_MESSAGE_BODY, it will create a variable of type char called temperature.

You will need to get your temperature value into a string (array of char) using sprintf() or similar to convert from the base type (float, double?).

Replace const TEXT_MESSAGE_BODY [] ... etc with :

```
strcat(data,"temperature");

char temperature_s[20];
sprintf(temperature_s, "%f", rawTemperature);
strcat(data,temperature_s);
```

Above assumes rawTemperature is a float holding the value read from the sensor, but the same idea applies for other data types..  There is no checking for buffer overflow etc, but you get the idea.